# Flot: Hoverable x-axis markings

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I'd like to make hoverable tooltips for x-axis markings, I used basically the same code in this demo.

http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/annotating.html

Imagine the text next to the vertical lines hidden, and when you mouse over the markings, the text were to show up. That's basically what I am trying to accomplish. I have tried using the `flothover` event but markings don't show up in those. Is there a plugin or something that performs a similar action?

Comment: I assume you mean plothover and not flothover? Also, some code from your implementation might help.

Comment: Try http://joeloughton.com/blog/web-applications/flot-plugins-event-graphics/

Answer (score 1):

Try binding to the x-axis marking div instead.

```
$(".flot-x-axis .tickLabel").bind("mouseover",functionThatDisplaysTooltip);
```